# Load user control with Jquery Ajax call

Tags: .net, ajax

I am trying to insert a user control on a page using JQuery

My Page looks like this

```
<asp:Content ID="Body" ContentPlaceHolderID="body" runat="server">    
    <div id="Container">

    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

       function LoadUserControl(tabName) {
           $.ajax({
               type: "POST",
               url: ("TestHK.aspx?Show=" + tabName),
               success: function (html) {
                   document.getElementById('Container').innerHTML = html;                  
               },
               error: function (msg) {
                   alert('error' + msg);
               }
           });
        }

</asp:Content>
```

And on the code behind I have

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["Show"]))
            {
                GetControlHtml("~/userControls/TreeViewAreas.ascx");              
            }
        }

    public void GetControlHtml(string controlLocation)
    {
        var page = new Page();
        var userControl = (TreeViewAreas)page.LoadControl(controlLocation);
        userControl.ButtonIsVisible = true;
        userControl.HousekeeperId = 7190;
        userControl.AreasCovered  = new HousekeeperBusiness().GetAreas(7190);            
        page.Controls.Add(userControl);
        using (var textWriter = new StringWriter())
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Server.Execute(page, textWriter, false);
            Response.Write(textWriter.ToString());
            Response.End();    
        }                       
    }
```

But I am always getting

Error executing child request for handler 'System.Web.UI.Page'.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I believe you won't be adding an UserControl with a simple AJAX mechanism.

This is a good case for using an UpdatePanel, because you'll add new controls and the page will show them.

Note I don't think UpdatePanel as a good option, but I believe that it meets your requirement.

Comment: I believe you should use an update panel, because it'll be so hard to get an user control to load and show in your page with AJAX from scratch.

Answer (score 1):

This is what you want.  http://weblogs.asp.net/sanjeevagarwal/archive/2008/07/22/Dynamically-create-ASP.NET-user-control-using-ASP.NET-Ajax-and-Web-Service.aspx

Enjoy.